# ¿Cómo convertir a json los datos de un archivo txt accediendo a él a través de un URL en Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que descargue los datos de los satélites (se llaman datos TLE, por ejemplo: https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/weather.txt) para calcular el apuntado de una antena que deberá seguirlos.
Actualmente, tengo que cargarlos a mano antes de ejecutar el programa, pero los datos se actualizan muy rápido y además quisiera darle al usuario la capacidad de elegir de que satélite obtener los datos.

El problema es que tienen un formato muy específico y tampoco sé cómo hacer el `request()` de Internet para conseguirlo.

La estructura de los datos está compuesta por 3 líneas: nombre, línea 1 y línea 2:

[image: Datos TLE]

Y necesito recuperarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
ec1_tle = {"Norad": "ESTCUBE 1",
           "Linea1": "1 39161U 13021C   21026.18622615  .00000188  00000-0  37342-4 0  9999",
           "Linea2": "2 39161  97.9502 110.5937 0008490 244.1514 115.8810 14.72415311414813"}
```

Quisiera implementar el programa de forma que reconozca cada bloque de datos de 3 líneas y le pregunte al usuario de cual satélite quiere la información.
No sé si es el enfoque adecuado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Importante
>
> Te aclaro que en stackoverflow **no** se suelen responder preguntas como esta en las que **no se proporciona código**. Si lo hice es solo porque me pareció interesante como ejercicio para iterar en una lista extrayendo tres elementos por cada ciclo. En futuro si quieres que tu pregunta sea bien recibida intenta escribir el código tu mismo y si te bloqueas compártelo exponiendo la duda.

### Explicación

Puedes utilizar la librería `urllib` para obtener los datos de la url. Crear una clase para construir objetos "satélites" que luego sean convertidos a json (que es el formato que al parecer deseas).

Noté que el archivo de texto online contiene muchos espacios en blanco al final de algunas líneas y por eso tuve que utilizar la función `rstrip` para deshacerme de esos espacios sin afectar los espacios que separan palabras o números en las líneas.

La solución que se me ocurrió para crear los objetos fue iterar la lista de las líneas de 3 en 3. Estoy seguro de que existe alguna función que lo hará de forma optimizada, pero como no la conozco lo que hice fue dividir por 3 la longitud de la lista para iterar en ella un número de veces equivalente a un tercio (1/3) del total de sus elementos, accediendo así a los tres elementos e incrementando sus tres índices (para la siguiente iteración) en cada ciclo.

Luego convierto los objetos de la lista `satelite` en formato json usando `json.dumps`.

Imprimo los datos en formato json y dejo un ejemplo de cómo se pueden manipular ulteriormente los datos en este formato.

Por último dejo un ejemplo de cómo se pueden obtener los datos de satélites específicos usando sus nombres como parámetro de búsqueda.

### Solución

*Datos del ejemplo:*

```
# Ejemplo datos
datos = """NOAA 15                 
1 25338U 98030A   21048.45475752  .00000015  00000-0  24961-4 0  9997
2 25338  98.6961  77.9723 0009350 269.6793  90.3316 14.26013306184142
DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147) 
1 25991U 99067A   21048.49146279 -.00000102  00000-0 -28111-4 0  9996
2 25991  99.0030  28.1250 0010682 121.6397 345.0782 14.16461350 95131"""
```

*Este es el código:*

```
import json
import urllib.request

# Carga el archivo desde el URL
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/weather.txt') as f:
   datos = f.read().decode('utf-8')

# rstrip() elimina los espacios en blanco que hay al final de algunas lineas
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in datos.splitlines()]

class Satelite:
    """ Crea objeto satelite """
    def __init__(self, nombre, linea1, linea2):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.linea1 = linea1
        self.linea2 = linea2

satelites=[]
# Indices
x, y, z = 0, 1, 2
# Itera cada 3 elementos
for i in range(int(len(lines)/3)):
    # Creo objeto y lo agrego a lista
    satelites.append(Satelite(lines[x], lines[y], lines[z]))
    # Incremento indices
    x+=3;y+=3;z+=3

# Convierte objeto satelite en json
datosJson=[json.dumps(s.__dict__) for s in satelites] 

# Analiza json
analizado=[json.loads(datosJson[i]) for i in range(len(datosJson))] 

# Imprime lista desempaquetada (Para ejemplo)
print('Metodo 1:\n', *datosJson)

# Imprime json indentado (Para ejemplo)
print('\nMetodo 2:')
for i in analizado:
    print(json.dumps(analizado, indent=4))

# Busca satelite por nombre
query = input("Nombre satelite: ")
resultados=0
for sat in analizado:
    if sat['nombre'].lower()==query.lower():
        print(sat)
        resultados+=1
    if analizado.index(sat)+1==len(analizado) and resultados==0:
        print("No hay satelites con ese nombre")
```

*Lo que devuelve (dejé solo dos satélites para simplificar):*

```
Metodo 1:
{"nombre": "NOAA 15", "linea1": "1 25338U 98030A   21048.45475752  .00000015  00000-0  24961-4 0  9997", "linea2": "2 25338  98.6961  77.9723 0009350 269.6793  90.3316 14.26013306184142"} {"nombre": "DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147)", "linea1": "1 25991U 99067A   21048.49146279 -.00000102  00000-0 -28111-4 0  9996", "linea2": "2 25991  99.0030  28.1250 0010682 121.6397 345.0782 14.16461350 95131"}

Metodo 2:
{
    "nombre": "NOAA 15",
    "linea1": "1 25338U 98030A   21048.45475752  .00000015  00000-0  24961-4 0  9997",
    "linea2": "2 25338  98.6961  77.9723 0009350 269.6793  90.3316 14.26013306184142"
}
{
    "nombre": "DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147)",
    "linea1": "1 25991U 99067A   21048.49146279 -.00000102  00000-0 -28111-4 0  9996",
    "linea2": "2 25991  99.0030  28.1250 0010682 121.6397 345.0782 14.16461350 95131"
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo comprendo, soy nuevo en esta comunidad y no tengo aun sltura con ella, la próxima vez intentará aportar mi propio código.

Comment: Si el usuario no conociera los nombres, ¿como puedo imprimir una lista sólo de nombres?

Comment: Crea una lista nombres y la imprime: `nombres=[sat["nombre"] for sat in analizado]; print(*nombres, sep="\n")`

Comment: Muchas gracias Ariel, una última duda si me lo permites. Estoy intentando hacer que el programa pueda nutrirse de datos locales cuando no tenga internet, pero estoy encontrando dificultades a la hora de leer el archivo txt ya que al recuperarlo de internet lo guarda de una forma distinta, dejando una línea en blanco entre cada línea de datos ¿Cómo podría enfocar ese problema?

Comment: Inténtalo y publica una pregunta si te bloqueas en algún punto especifico.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429511/crear-una-string-desde-un-fichero-txt