# Imprimir lista de datos a partir de JSON

Tags: python, json

Asociado a una duda anterior ([¿Cómo convertir a json los datos de un archivo txt accediendo a él a través de un URL en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428991/c%c3%b3mo-convertir-a-json-los-datos-de-un-archivo-txt-accediendo-a-%c3%a9l-a-trav%c3%a9s-de-u)) quería imprimir una lista de posibilidades al usuario.
El código es el siguiente:

```
class Satelite:
    
    """ Crea objeto satelite """
    def __init__(self, nombre, linea1, linea2):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.linea1 = linea1
        self.linea2 = linea2

satelites=[]

# Indices
x, y, z = 0, 1, 2

# Itera cada 3 elementos
for i in range(int(len(lines)/3)):
    
    # Creo objeto y lo agrego a lista
    satelites.append(Satelite(lines[x], lines[y], lines[z]))
    
    # Incremento indices
    x += 3; y += 3; z += 3

# Convierte objeto satelite en json
datosJson = [json.dumps(s.__dict__) for s in satelites] 

# Analiza json
analizado = [json.loads(datosJson[i]) for i in range(len(datosJson))] 

# Imprime lista desempaquetada (Para ejemplo)
print('Metodo 1:\n', *datosJson)

# Imprime json indentado (Para ejemplo)
print('\nMetodo 2:')
for i in analizado:
    print(json.dumps(analizado, indent=4))

# Busca satelite por nombre
query = input("Nombre satelite: ")
resultados=0
for sat in analizado:
    if sat['nombre'].lower()==query.lower():
        print(sat)
        resultados+=1
    if analizado.index(sat)+1==len(analizado) and resultados==0:
        print("No hay satelites con ese nombre")
```

Quisiera imprimir la línea x, no se cual es el argumento correcto para ello.

Answer (score 0):

Ya me lo respondieron en la pregunta anterior. Lo que hay que hacer es otra lista e imprimirla:

```
 nombres=[sat["nombre"] for sat in analizado]
 print("Lista de satélites:\n")
```