# Cargar datos JSON en variable

Tags: python, json

Estoy intentando leer unos datos relacionado a una anterior pregunta ([¿Cómo convertir a json los datos de un archivo txt accediendo a él a través de un URL en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428991/c%c3%b3mo-convertir-a-json-los-datos-de-un-archivo-txt-accediendo-a-%c3%a9l-a-trav%c3%a9s-de-u)) y una vez leidos y convertidos a JSON me gustaría introducirlos en una variable para introducirlo en otro programa.

```
class Satelite:
    
    """ Crea objeto satelite """
    def __init__(self, nombre, linea1, linea2):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.linea1 = linea1
        self.linea2 = linea2

satelites=[]

# Indices
x, y, z = 0, 1, 2

# Itera cada 3 elementos
for i in range(int(len(lines)/3)):
    
    # Creo objeto y lo agrego a lista
    satelites.append(Satelite(lines[x], lines[y], lines[z]))
    
    # Incremento indices
    x += 3; y += 3; z += 3

# Convierte objeto satelite en json
datosJson = [json.dumps(s.__dict__) for s in satelites] 

# Analiza json
analizado = [json.loads(datosJson[i]) for i in range(len(datosJson))]
```

Así es como se crean los datos.
Necesito introducirlos en una variable de la siguiente estructura:

```
ec1_tle = {"Norad": "ESTCUBE 1",
           "Linea1": "1 39161U 13021C   21026.18622615  .00000188  00000-0  37342-4 0  9999",
           "Linea2": "2 39161  97.9502 110.5937 0008490 244.1514 115.8810 14.72415311414813"}
```

¿Sería más viable si no cambiar la forma en que el otro programa me pide la variable?

Comment: Veo que tienes una Lista que contiene tus datos en forma de diccionario Python. Si tu deseas es guardar uno de los datos en una variable. Puedes especificar por medio del índice de la Lista a cual dato quieres apuntar. Ejemplo aquí apuntas al primer dato : ec1_tle = analizado[0]  o al segundo dato: ec1_tle = analizado[1]
Por favor, corrígeme si lo que deseas es otra cosa, quizás entendí mal.

Comment: No se si me he explicado bien. Lo que quiero es decir que ec1_tle = analizado [0] + analizado [1] + analizado [3]

Comment: Entiendo. Quieres que todos tu datos estén en un diccionario en vez de una Lista. es decir, que puedas apuntar al nombre de un satélite y obtengas sus datos. algo como esto ec1_tle["ESTCUBE 1"] 
y el resultado sea:
 {"Linea1": "1 39161U 13021C   21026.18622615  .00000188  00000-0  37342-4 0  9999","Linea2": "2 39161  97.9502 110.5937 0008490 244.1514 115.8810 14.72415311414813"}}

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que busco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso tienes que crear un nuevo diccionario y recorrer tu lista de datos para ir añadiendo los campos y valor que deseas. Algo como esto

```py
sateliteDict = {}
for satelite in analizado:
    sateliteDict[satelite["nombre"]] ={"linea1":satelite["linea1"],"linea2":satelite["linea2"]}
```

1. Creas un diccionario python vacío.
2. iteras (recorres) los elementos que conforman tu lista *analizado*
3. En cada iteración obtienes un diccionario con uno de tus datos y los usas para ir añadiendo esos datos al nuevo diccionario

De esa manera, ahora puedes especificar un satélite y obtener sus datos. Ejemplo:

```py
print(sateliteDict["METEOSAT-8 (MSG-1)"])
```

Resultado:

```py
{'linea1': '1 27509U 02040B   21049.74504515  .00000137  00000-0  00000-0 0  9997', 'linea2': '2 27509   7.1595  53.0285 0000894 336.2674  69.3558  1.00279355 67761'}
```