# Crear una string desde un fichero txt

Tags: python

Estoy leyendo un archivo txt desde mi escritorio que anteriormente he descargado así:

```
TLE = urllib.request.urlopen(Url)
    Datos = TLE.read().decode('utf-8')
    file = open("C:/Users/TFG/Desktop/Programas/TLE.txt", "w")
    file.write(Datos)
    file.close()
```

El problema es que  el archivo original extraído de internet tiene esta forma:

NOAA 15
1 25338U 98030A   21050.13872594  .00000012  00000-0  23468-4 0  9998
2 25338  98.6960  79.6435 0009359 264.2251  95.7862 14.26013460184381
DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147)
1 25991U 99067A   21050.17812681 -.00000083  00000-0 -18759-4 0  9996
2 25991  99.0033  29.8304 0010740 117.2026 305.4670 14.16461246 95373

Y lo que guarda es de la siguiente forma:

NOAA 15

1 25338U 98030A   21050.13872594  .00000012  00000-0  23468-4 0  9998

2 25338  98.6960  79.6435 0009359 264.2251  95.7862 14.26013460184381

DMSP 5D-3 F15 (USA 147)

1 25991U 99067A   21050.17812681 -.00000083  00000-0 -18759-4 0  9996

2 25991  99.0033  29.8304 0010740 117.2026 305.4670 14.16461246 95373

Como veis, le ha añadido un espacio en blanco que me estorba bastante a la hora de conseguir mi objetivo, que es leer el fichero y almacenar los datos en una clase formada por nombre, linea 1 y linea 2.
No se si para conseguirlo tengo que modificar el proceso de escritura, lectura o el proceso de formar la string.
Así es como lo estoy intentando leer:

```
#Proceso para leer datos locales de TLE.txt
    print("Usamos datos locales\n")
    Archivo = 'C:/Users/TFG/Desktop/Programas/TLE.txt'
    
    f = open(Archivo, 'r')
    Datos = f.read()
    f.close()

    # rstrip() elimina los espacios en blanco que hay al final de algunas lineas
    lines = [line.lstrip().rstrip() for line in Datos.splitlines()]
```

Comment: Olvidé decirte que si usas `with open()` luego no tienes que preocuparte por cerrar manualmente el archivo.

Comment: Gracias, me lo apunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código presenta un error de indentación y la dirección del slash en el directorio es incorrecta, tienes `/` y debería ser `\`.

Para declarar un directorio de Windows en Python es recomendable utilizar `\\` porque en Python existen cosas como `\n` o `\t` (entre otras) que crearán problemas si alguna carpeta o archivo del directorio inicia con alguna de estas letras, este problema se soluciona con el uso del doble slash el cual especifica al compilador de interpretarlo como un slash simple sin tomar en cuenta la letra a continuación.

También puede ser sensato incluir un control para ver si el archivo existe y así evitar que el programa se cierre con un error al intentar abrir un archivo inexistente.

> ## “
>
> No se si para conseguirlo tengo que modificar el proceso de escritura, lectura o el proceso de formar la string.

No hay una forma mejor que otra, el problema puede resolverse de varias maneras y todas son correctas.

A continuación te dejo una manera de como puedes hacer la lectura del archivo correctamente.

```
from os.path import isfile

archivo = 'C:\\Users\\TFG\\Desktop\\Programas\\TLE.txt'

# Controla si el archivo existe
if isfile(archivo):

    with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
        datos = [linea for linea in f.readlines() if linea != "\n"]

else:
    print("Archivo inexistente")
```